# How to find if one dictionary keys exist in other dict values. and remove matching values from first dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionary like below, what I need to find if dict A values matches any of the dict B keys, if it does; I need to find out if values from dict A equals any value in dict B values. matching value has be removed from dict A values. I tried something like this to solve with pythonic way, but couldn't get it to work.

```
 key_match={k: [val for val in A.values()] for [k,v for k,v in  B.items()] if val==B.get(k) and k in A.values() A.remove(val) }

A = {'P1': ['fit', 'style','unique', 'color', 'true size'],
     'P2': ['fit','comfortable','large','awesome','taper']}

B = {'style': ['girlish', 'stylishly', 'sophisticated'],
     'active': ['lifestyle','playing','activity'],
     'fit': ['comfortable','front-runner','relaxing']}
```

example output: should be updated dict A

```
 'P2': ['fit','large','awesome','taper']
```

Comment: in dict `A` 'P1' also has 'fit' why it's not included in output?

Comment: I just gave one example from dict A, since P1 values contains only the key from second dictionary but not any values, there is no changes need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is.  You need to iterate with nested loops through the items() of both dictionaries:

```
A = {'P1': ['fit', 'style','unique', 'color', 'true size'],
     'P2': ['fit','comfortable','large','awesome','taper']}

B = {'style': ['girlish', 'stylishly', 'sophisticated'],
     'active': ['lifestyle','playing','activity'],
     'fit': ['comfortable','front-runner','relaxing']}

for bkey, bvalues in B.items():
    for akey, avalues in A.items():
        if bkey in avalues:
            for avalue in avalues:
                for bvalue in bvalues:
                    if avalue == bvalue:
                        A_copy = dict(A)
                        A_copy[akey].remove(avalue)
                        A = A_copy
print(A)
```

Comment: Thank you pakpe! This is perfect and really fast too:)))

Comment: You are welcome, Gunsu.  I am glad I was able to help you seconds before they closed your question.

Comment: Thanks again! I have multiple attempts but couldn't wrap my head around it. Very long day!. I don't know why they close the question. Doesn't make sense!

Comment: Next time, post a portion of your code, even if it is wrong.  They close the posts if they think you haven't done any work on your own to solve it.

Comment: will do thank you!